# What does initializing word with previous initialized word do in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

What do the second and third line in data segment do? When I move `ptr1` into `bx`, it shows up as A. And I don't understand what's happening here?

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    val1 dw 0df53h
    ptr1 dw val1
    ptr2 dw ptr1
.code
    main    proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov al, byte ptr val1+1
    mov bx, ptr1
    xchg ax, bx
    dec bl
    mov ax, ptr2
    neg al

        mov   ax,4c00h
        int   21h
    main    endp
end main
```

Comment: Labels are addresses. So the second puts the address of `val1` in `ptr1` and similarly for the third line. They are pointers (as the name suggests).

Comment: `val1` is located at `.data + 0 `; `ptr1` is located at `.data + 2` and `ptr2` is located at `.data + 4`.